# ASP.NET Core Rewrite not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-rewrite-module

I have a `RewriteExtension` class (using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite` library) and have a check for this url:

```
https://internal.mtls.authenticate.dev.myapplication/Redirect
```

upon which I need to remove 'internal.mtls' so that the redirect can happen to

```
https://authenticate.dev.myapplication/Redirect
```

The redirect does happen and based on the log `Redirecting to {url}` (see code below) the `internal.mtls` was removed as expected. i.e. `Redirecting to "https://authenticate.dev.myapplication/Redirect"`

However, in the Redirect controller I log `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value` and the value is 'still' `internal.mtls.authenticate.dev.myapplication`.

My expectation is of course `authenticate.dev.myapplication`.
What is the potential reason for the domain still containing `mtls.internal` after explicitly removing it?

This is the code:

```
 if (ShouldRedirectToTlsDomain(request))
 {
      string url = RemoveMtlsFromUrl($" 
      {request.Scheme}://{request.Host}");
      var path = request.Path.Value;
      var redirectTo = new Uri(new Uri(RemoveMtlsFromUrl(url)), 
                                     path).AbsoluteUri;
       var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Moved;
        Log.Information("Redirecting to {url}", redirectTo);
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = redirectTo;
}
```

This is the configuration in `Startup`

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
 .AddRedirectToNonMtlsDomain(
     new Uri(appConfig.MtlsBaseUrl, UriKind.Absolute)));
```

Comment: have tried to test issue in the incognito mode? have tried some other tool like postman to test the issue? try to debug the code with break point to see the value of redirect url. may i know do you have any other middleware configured in your code?